# How can I display multiple return values of a recursive function efficiently?

Tags: function, recursion, computer-science

I will be using JavaScript to demonstrate my example, but the question remains open to other programming languages as well.

Let's consider a simple recursive function:

```
function f(x){
    if(x>1) return f(x-1)+5;
    else return 3;
}
```

Let's say I want to display the value of the function for all x from 1 to 5, where x is an integer. The most obvious solution would be the following:

```
for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
    console.log(f(i));
}
```

This method, however, seems incredibly inefficient, as we are calling the function 5+4+3+2+1 times. Intuitively, only 5 function calls would be necessary, as whenever we want the value of f(5), it is necessary to find the value of f(4) f(3) f(2) and f(1) first, so after finding f(5), we wouldn't need to call f(4) and start the entire process all over again to just to find the value of f(4) which we already found once.

Any ideas?

Comment: Search term: memoization

Comment: If you were writing Python, you'd simple write `@functools.cache` in front of the function and it would do exactly what you want.  As @Mat points out, you want memoization.